# Kubectl get pods - How to filter pods by partial name

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

The command `kubectl get pods <POD NAME>` will return the specific pod with that name. I wonder if there is a way that I can use part of the name, for instance, a command that returns all pods that start with `j`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Linux Bash:

```sh
kubectl get pods | grep ^j
```

In Windows PowerShell:

```sh
kubectl get pods | Select-String '^j'
```

Comment: Filter with grep or equivalent is the only way.

Regex/glob filtering in `kubectl` was proposed and rejected several times:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/109400
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/107053
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/107285

Answer (score 9):

I am using the service name as a filter. it is kind of easier.

```
kubectl get pods -l service=usercontent
```

or something like this

```
kubectl get pods -l app=rabbit
```

You will get all pods that related this service. If you have multiple databases pods or apps it is quite useful.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Not a 'sql-like' but 'all the pods related to a deployment. Your command didn't work on my k8s-minikube local installation, I did a little modification: after a full list of details, got by 'kubectl describe pods', I did 'kubectl get pods -l app=xxx'

Answer (score 2):

Filter without grep (unfortunately requires full name):

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector metadata.name=<your_pod_name>
```

this works for me. Of course you have to precise the namespace if not set in the current-context

Comment: if you go by the full name, you can just do `kubectl get pod <fullname>`

Answer (score 1):

If you have `crictl` installed in your node:

```
 crictl pods --name '^j'
```