# How to get the full name of a pod by both its creation date and part of its name?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In my namespace, I have several pods named with the same prefix, followed by the random string. There are also other pods, named differently. The result of `kubectl get pods` would look something like this:

```
service-job-12345abc
service-job-abc54321
other-job-54321cba
```

I need to find the nameof the most recently created pod starting with "service-job-".

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829475/get-name-of-most-recently-created-pod), which helps getting the name of the most recent pod in general. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70282381/kubectl-get-pods-how-to-filter-pods-by-partial-name) gets me the complete names of pods starting with a specific prefix.

What I struggle with is combining these two methods. With each one, I seem to lose the information I need to perform the other one.

Note: I am not an administrator of the cluster, so I cannot change anything about the naming etc. of the pods. The pods could also be in any possible state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as you expect:

```
kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' | grep service-job- | head -1
```

Comment: For some reason templates always throw errors for me, and I failed to mention that I am forced to work with Powershell. However, the sorting and selecting does work as expected, so I am accepting this answer as correct. My tweaked version that works for me is this: `kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" | select-string service-job- | Select-Object -Last 1`